# problema con LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Con esta función muestro una lista de ejercicios pertenecientes a un curso que provienen de una tabla llamada "lessons" con las siguientes columnas importantes:

```
 lessons.id, lessons.number, lessons.course_id entre otras.
```

todos los usuarios ven los mismo user_id está de adorno de una de mis prueba, para tomar el valor despues

```
    public function get_lessons($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons = array();
    $get_lessons = $db->query("SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE course_id=$course_id ORDER BY lesson_number DESC") or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
    if($get_lessons->num_rows > 0) {
        while($lesson = $get_lessons->fetch_assoc()) {
            $lessons[] = $lesson;
        }
    }
    return $lessons;
}
```

y muestro los resultados con un

```
foreach
```

Hasta aquí todo va excelente.

El punto es que ahora me gustaría mostrar al usuario si ya ha completado tal o cual ejercicio, para lo cual previamente se insertó el status en la tabla "lessons_completed" con las siguientes columnas importantes

```
lessons_completed.lesson_number, lessons_completed.user_id, lessons_completed.course_id  entre otras
```

Con esta función

```
    public function get_lessons_completed($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons_completed = array();


   $get_lessons_completed = $db->query
         (
             "SELECT
         lessons.lesson_id,
         lessons.course_id,
         lessons.lesson_number,
         lessons.lesson_intro,
         lessons.lesson_text,
         lessons.lesson_date,
         lessons.lesson_prev,
         lessons.lesson_top,
         lessons_completed.lesson_number,
         lessons_completed.completed
         FROM lessons
         WHERE course_id=$course_id
         LEFT JOIN lessons_completed ON
         lessons.lesson_number = lessons_completed.lesson_number WHERE 
         user_id=$user_id"

                )
                or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
         if($get_lessons_completed->num_rows > 0) {
         while($lesson_completed = $get_lessons_completed->fetch_assoc()) {
            $lessons_completed[] = $lesson_completed;
        }
        }
        return $lessons_completed;
        }
```

Sin embargo obtengo un error 500 y la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal, o si es el procedimiento correcto. espero que algún amigo me pueda ayudar, puede ser que mi error este en el segundo WHERE, pero ya lo quite y da el mismo, error, elimino todo el LEFT JOIN junto con las dos consultas a la segunda tabla y funciona nuevamente mostrando solo los registros tal como la primera función.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis, existen dos WHERE''s

Comment: el error 500 no deberia ser error de consulta...

Comment: Es cierto, el error 500 está mas relacionado con el servidor (infraestructura) aún así tienes un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tienes un error de sintaxis en tu query, estas utilizando 2 `where`, porque?

debiera ser así:

```
     SELECT
     lessons.lesson_id,
     lessons.course_id,
     lessons.lesson_number,
     lessons.lesson_intro,
     lessons.lesson_text,
     lessons.lesson_date,
     lessons.lesson_prev,
     lessons.lesson_top,
     lessons_completed.lesson_number,
     lessons_completed.completed
     FROM lessons
     LEFT JOIN lessons_completed 
     ON lessons.lesson_number = lessons_completed.lesson_number 
     WHERE lessons.course_id=$course_id 
     AND lessons.user_id=$user_id
```

Puedes probar esta query primero en tu motor de base de datos y ver si te devuelve resultados esperados?

saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya probe con tu respuesta y me sigue arrojando Error 500, puse 2 Where intentando que el primero llamara sólo los ejercicios del curso, y el segundo para intentar obtener sólo los registros del usuario en ese mismo curso.

Comment: pruebala de nuevo, la edite, pero corre la query en tu motor de base de datos..
debes corroborar que el query este correcta, si es así, el problema lo tienes en la aplicación... me cuentas

Comment: Gracias Francisco, al probarla directamente el el motor , me dice lo siguiente: #1052 - La columna: 'course_id' en where clause es ambigua

Comment: Sin importar a qué id de curso llame, me dice lo mismo.

Comment: es porque debes agregar el nombre de la tabla al principio de la columna, asi:  `lessons.course_id= ''` y tambien con `user.id`

Comment: Muchas gracias!, ya quedó, son unos genios!!! un fuerte abrazo!

Comment: de nada antonio, no olvides marcar la respuesta con ticket si fue de tu ayuda. un abrazo

Answer (score 0):

**Primero :** mencionarte que el error 500 va relacionado con tu servidor (infraestructura).

**Segundo :** Tienes un error de sintaxis, corrige poniendo un solo WHERE y añade un alias a tu tabla "lessons_completed":

Prueba primero reemplazando tus variables con valores estáticos:

```
   SELECT
     lessons.lesson_id,
     lessons.course_id,
     lessons.lesson_number,
     lessons.lesson_intro,
     lessons.lesson_text,
     lessons.lesson_date,
     lessons.lesson_prev,
     lessons.lesson_top,
     LC.lesson_number,
     LC.completed
     FROM lessons
     LEFT JOIN lessons_completed LC
     ON lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number 
   WHERE lessons.course_id = 5 --Prueba con un valor estatico 
    AND lessons.user_id = 'guest' --Prueba con un valor estatico
```

Si eso te funciona en entonces puede que algo este mal con tu código php.

También podrías probar primero en tu IDE de BD.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si ya corregi el WHERE y coloque valores estáticos y me arroja el mismo error 500 desde el navegador y el IDE me dice que course_id es ambiguo

Comment: Ok, falto anteponer el alias en tus condiciones. He editado la respuesta, puedes volver a verificar.

Comment: Excelente, mil gracias a ti a y Francisco, ya funciona correctamente!!!!!

Comment: De nada, espero te haya ayudado. Puedes puntuar la respuesta para que pueda ayudar a otros con la misma duda.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias!! funciona perfectamente con este código:

```
    public function get_lessons_completed($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons_completed = array();


   $get_lessons_completed = $db->query
         (
             "SELECT
   lessons.lesson_id,
   lessons.course_id,
   lessons.lesson_number,
   lessons.lesson_intro,
   lessons.lesson_text,
   lessons.lesson_date,
   lessons.lesson_prev,
   lessons.lesson_top,
   LC.lesson_number,
   LC.completed
   FROM lessons
   LEFT JOIN lessons_completed LC
   ON lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number
   WHERE lessons.course_id = $course_id
   AND lessons.user_id = $user_id"

                )
                or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
    if($get_lessons_completed->num_rows > 0) {
        while($lesson_completed = $get_lessons_completed->fetch_assoc()) {
            $lessons_completed[] = $lesson_completed;
        }
    }
    return $lessons_completed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acomode el query de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT l.lesson_id, 
    l.course_id, 
    l.lesson_number, 
    l.lesson_intro, 
    l.lesson_text, 
    l.lesson_date, 
    l.lesson_prev, 
    l.lesson_top, 
    lc.lesson_number, 
    lc.completed FROM lessons l WHERE l.course_id=$course_id LEFT JOIN lessons_completed lc ON l.lesson_number = lc.lesson_number WHERE l.user_id=$user_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

decidí hacer otra consulta aquí mismo ya que es el mismo tema, y yo creo que ya se me calento la cabeza, porque estoy seguro que me falta algo.

Con el código de ayer el LEFT JOIN funciona de mil maravillas, sin embargo, borre todos los registros de la tabla *lessons_completed* y como era obvio me dejo de mostrar los ejercicios de la tabla *lessons*, y si agrego registros del usuario en la tabla *lessons_completed*  me van apareciendo los ejercicios con su respectivo check, eso está muy bien, pero ya no me muestra los ejercicios que aún no ha completado el usuario.

para mostrar el check sólo utilizo un if a la columna:

```
if $lesson[completed]==1 {
muestro el check 
}  else { 
   NO OK
}
```

En la columna *lessons_completed.completed* sólo hay valores 1 el 0 no existe porque el registro se crea cuando el usuario hace click en *Completada* con un insert

Vuelvo a agregar el código como quedó después de las recomendaciones de ustedes

```
     public function get_lessons_completed($args = array()) {
    global $db;
    $user_id = !isset($args['user_id']) ? null : $args['user_id'];
    $course_id = !isset($args['course_id']) ? null : $args['course_id'];
    $lessons_completed = array();

            $get_lessons_completed = $db->query
            ("SELECT
                 lessons.lesson_id,
                 lessons.course_id,
                 lessons.lesson_number,
                 lessons.lesson_intro,
                 lessons.lesson_text,
                 lessons.lesson_date,
                 lessons.lesson_prev,
                 lessons.lesson_top,
                 LC.lesson_number,
                     LC.completed
                 FROM lessons

                 LEFT JOIN lessons_completed LC

                 ON lessons.lesson_number = LC.lesson_number

               WHERE lessons.course_id = 2 AND LC.user_id= 2 ORDER BY 
            lessons.lesson_number

            ") or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);

          if($get_lessons_completed->num_rows > 0) {
            while($lesson_completed = $get_lessons_completed->fetch_assoc()) {

            $lessons_completed[] = $lesson_completed;
        }
     }
      return $lessons_completed;
     }
```

Hasta aquí todo excelente, Ahora la pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo hacer o que me falta para traer los ejercicios de la tabla *lessons* que aún no ha completado el usuario? sin que se dupliquen los registros con los que el usuario ya completo?

Aquí se muestran los resultados con el código de arriba, pero hay por ejemplo en este ID DE CURSO en la tabla *lessons* otros 6 ejercicios que he intentado traer, pero se me duplican con los que ya completo el usuario si hago cambios a la función

[image: Resultado de la función de arriba]

Intente trayendo los nulos con un:

```
OR NULL
```

y el resultado es que se duplican

Ya intente cambiando a INNER y a RIGTH en mi desesperación pero el resultado es el mismo, me trae los mismos datos de la misma forma que como esta actualmente.

Quiza lo ideal sería agregando otro JOIN pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Espero me puedan ayudar amigos.  creo que nunca me había enfrentado a resolver una situación que no puedo resolver por mi  mismo, esos JOIN me traen mareado.